# Fix broken rpm on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, yum, rpm

I get the following error when I type `rpm`:

```
rpm: error while loading shared libraries: librpm-4.3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How could this library have gone missing? How can I get these packages and fix my version of `rpm` for my OS (CentOS 6.7)? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Navigate to the [Centos Mirror](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/).
2. Select your architecture (i386 for 32bit, x86_64 for 64bit)
3. Click the *Packages* link
4. Download the **rpm-libs-4.8.0-55.el6.[arch].rpm** package.
5. cd to the root directory `cd /`
6. Unpack the rpm using:
   `sudo rpm2cpio /path/to/rpm-libs-4.8.0-55.el6.[arch].rpm | cpio -idmv`

This will unpack and install 3 libraries and 3 symlinks in the package to where they belong.

If you are more cautious, unpack them to a working directory and manually move them over, paying strict attention to syslinks and permissions.

On my system (Centos 6.7, x86_64) the packages are in /usr/lib64 with the following permissions:

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     20 Oct 24 20:13 librpmbuild.so.1 -> librpmbuild.so.1.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 155344 May 10  2016 librpmbuild.so.1.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     17 Oct 24 20:13 librpmio.so.1 -> librpmio.so.1.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 183968 May 10  2016 librpmio.so.1.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     15 Oct 24 20:13 librpm.so.1 -> librpm.so.1.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 435496 May 10  2016 librpm.so.1.0.0
```

Comment: Thanks; I can't run this, though, because `rpm2cpio` depends upon the same library.

Comment: In this case, you will probably need to unpack the files on another Linux host and manually move them into place on the effected host. Unpack the RPM as a normal user (not sudo) into a working directory. After moving them into place, set the permissions as above. (chown root:root librpm*)